# How to prevent textarea from overlapping list

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a messenger app working but there is one problem that the textbox overlaps the messages. **My HTML:**

```
<div>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  </div>
  <form onsubmit="return sendMessage();">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>
  <textarea id="message" placeholder="Enter message..." rows="3" cols="195"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submitibtn">
  </div>
  </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#message {
     resize: none;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 70px;
 }
 
 #message:hover {
     border: 2px solid black;
 }
 
 #submitibtn {
     background-color: cornflowerblue;
     width: 1580px;
     height: 30px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
 }
 
 #submitibtn:hover {
     border: 2px solid blue;
 }
```

[Website](https://messengerwebapp.firebaseapp.com/) if you want to see it for yourself:
https://messengerwebapp.firebaseapp.com/
(Login as anonymous and send a message then see the textarea overlapping the messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fixed positioning, you can give the div holding the messages a fixed height and overflow scroll. You will just need to play with the VH heights.

```css
#message {
         resize: none;
         height: 25vh;
       width: 100%;
     }
     
     .messages-wrapper{
        height:60vh;    
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:none;
     }
     
     #message:hover {
         border: 2px solid black;
     }
     
     #submitibtn {
         background-color: cornflowerblue;
         width: 100%;
         height:15vh;  
     }
     
     #submitibtn:hover {
         border: 2px solid blue;
     }
```

```html
<div class="messages-wrapper">
      <ul id="messages"><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li><li>aaaa</li></ul>
      </div>
      <form onsubmit="return sendMessage();">
      <div>
      <textarea id="message" placeholder="Enter message..." rows="3" cols="195"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="submitibtn">
      </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS. This is what is causing the issue

```
#message {
     resize: none;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 70px;
 }
```

Try this

```
#message {
     resize: none;
     height: 70px; /* THE HEIGHT SHOULD INHERIT YOUR ROWS ON THE TEXTAREA */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case this would work, although I would suggest you study html and css a little more and you will arrive to a much more clean and better structure:

```css
#messages {
    bottom: 76px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```